# Declaring protected attribute in interface

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to declare protected attributes in TypeScript interfaces?

For example:

```
interface IsDrawable {
  // protected // <- seems to be unsupported
  cssClass: string;
}

class SomeClass implements IsDrawable {
  protected // <- errors
  cssClass: string;
}
```

SomeClass errors with `Class 'SomeClass' incorrectly implements interface 'IsDrawable'.  Property 'cssClass' is protected in type 'SomeClass' but  public in type 'IsDrawable'.

Comment: you get error ==> Error, cannot widen visibility

Comment: please read more about interfaces here http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try to understand [sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_(computing)) of `Interface` in any languages.

Since `Interface` is schema that anyone can use to access some class features, its fields can not be private or protected

Comment: But if you follow https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25163#issuecomment-433643933 then clearly the question isn't without its grounds. Setting the visibility of a property in class without willing to define it in the Interface still causes TypeScript to throw this error which is misleading.

Answer (score 4):

An interface is a contract meaning you are telling entities outside of yourself what you can do and what you have, by making them protected you are breaking that contract.

That being said, you want to force the implementation of something scoped as protected, you can use abstract classes to fit that need. They are new as of version 1.6 https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3578

**Update**

`abstract` cannot be applied to properties, so in order to make this work, cssClass would need to be a method which would return the string.

Comment: Even though this works it's worth noting that the abstract class approach imposes inherent limitations (you can implement multiple interfaces but not inherit from multiple base-abstract-classes - one has to resort to using composition which in turn complicates things further)