What is the difference between defining interface outside and inside a class?
In my understanding, this is how you define interface inside class:
class A {
  a: number
  constructor() {
    this.a = 0
  }
}

And this is how you define interface outside class:
interface A {
  a: number
}
class A {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 0
  }
}

What is the difference between the two cases? When should I use one over the other? I notice that private and protected modifiers can't be used in interface, so if I need to use them then of course I need to use the inside case. But if I only use public, then it seems to be no difference between them?
Reading the documentation for Classes and Everyday Types doesn't help.

interface defines a public interface, allowing other modifiers would make no sense - https://stackoverflow.com/q/32888353/3001761.

if you don't export it, can it still be public?

The latter form is declaration merging. You've re-opened the class instance type and added the interface stuff to it. There are observable differences; stuff merged in won't be checked the same way. (e.g. with --useDefineForClassFields then there will be no Object.defineProperty() for a merged field; you can't assign readonly merged fields in the ctor, etc). You can certainly use readonly, but private doesn't work on an interface in general. Does this fully address the q? If so I'll write an a. If not, what's missing?

@jcalz I understand that this is declaration merging, but I don't get why a consequence of this is you can't use modifiers. Certainly I can only define an interface just for internal use, right?

You say “modifiers” but you certainly can use readonly and optional modifiers. If you want to know why protected or private aren’t supported in interface declarations that’s a fair question, I suppose, but can you please [edit] to clarify and distinguish between the modifiers because they are not the same thing.

I have edited it. Is it better? Note that my main question is the second one. The modifier question is just a side discovery when I research the problem.

Please [edit] this to ask a single primary question, or it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only." (If your main question is the second one then you should remove the other ones and consider posting them as their own question posts if you still need them answered after this one is answered.)

@jcalz is it better?

Yes, looks good. The difference is that declaration merging is primarily meant for "patching" types and circumvents checks. I would avoid that unless you need it for some reason. In this case there isn't a lot of difference, but there is a difference. Depending on your compiler options, you can see that different JS code is emitted. When a is just merged in, the class constructor doesn't emit field code for it. This can have observable runtime differences for more complicated situations. Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz yes, that answers the question. Having examples on those situations would be great. Would that also explain why the declaration merging disallows visibility modifiers as well?

What you're calling "defining an interface inside a class" is just the normal way you write classes. Fields generally are declared in the class:
class A {
  a: number
  constructor() {
    this.a = 0
  }
}

If you compile the above to target modern JavaScript and use the appropriate compiler options, it will produce a JavaScript class with a public class field:
// JavaScript
class A {
    a; // <-- public class field declaration
    constructor() {
        this.a = 0;
    }
}


On the other hand, what you're calling "defining an interface outside a class" is known as declaration merging. The interface merges with the class instance type, which sort of "patches" it at the type level. Interface declarations have absolutely no runtime effect, so anything you put in there that normally goes into the class declaration might behave differently. For example:
interface B {
  a: number
}
class B {
  constructor() {
    this.a = 0
  }
}

If you compile that with the same compiler settings as above, you will get the following JavaScript, without a class field declaration:
// JavaScript
class B {
    // <-- no public class field declaration
    constructor() {
        this.a = 0;
    }
}


The fact that the two approaches can result in different JavaScript is an indication that they are not identical, although there's little pragmatic difference in this example. Still, you could easily change things where there are noticeable differences:
class C { a?: number }
console.log(Object.keys(new C()).length) // 1

interface D { a?: number }
class D { }
console.log(Object.keys(new D()).length) // 0

And certainly there are type checking differences. Interface merging adds stuff without having to pass the normal sorts of type checks:
class E { a: number } // compiler error
//        ~
// Property 'a' has no initializer and is not definitely 
// assigned in the constructor.
new E().a.toFixed(); // runtime error

interface F { a: number }
class F { } // no compiler error
new F().a.toFixed(); // runtime error

In the above, E gives you a compiler error that you forgot to initialize a, whereas F does not give you that error, even though the same problem exists. So E warns you about an issue that F doesn't notice.

Also, interfaces are not class declarations, so many class-specific things you can normally do are not available in interface merging.  The most obvious example is that classes allow you to write runtime code, whereas interfaces do not. You can initialize class fields and implement class methods, but "initializing" an interface property or "implementing" an interface method doesn't make much sense:
class G { a: number = 1; b(): number { return 2 } };

interface H { a: number = 1, b(): number { return 2 }} // errors!

Any class-specific modifiers like private or protected or static or abstract are unavailable in interfaces:
abstract class I {
  abstract a: number;
  private b?: number;
  static c: number;
}

interface J {
  abstract a: number; // error!
  private b?: number; // error!
  static c: number; // error!
}


As for what you should do, this is at least somewhat subjective. In my opinion, declaration merging is an advanced technique that you only use to work around limitations in existing code. If you can do something without using it, you should.
Playground link to code

"declaration merging is an advanced technique that you only use to work around limitations in existing code" — can you give examples of those limitations, and how using it solves the problem? I can only think of an instance that the maintainer import a class without fields and need to use interface instead, and do it with the keyword as in every new instance. It's that correct? And in those cases, why doesn't the library author use the fields (assuming they know about it)

You can use it to monkey patch existing classes with new fields or members (so the library author didn't know about them). Sometimes things will be implemented with class Foo {} and then later Foo.prototype.member = , so you need to merge member into Foo for that to work.

so interface is not really for typing properties/fields/members declared in class, but for those declared via prototype?
